# spring-data jpa возможно ли дать права пользователю?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

использую spring-data-jpa и postgresql, возможно ли через какую-нибудь аннотацию дать права конкретному пользователю на чтение таблицы, например через script я записал бы так:

```
GRANT SELECT ON schema.table1 TO user_r;
GRANT SELECT ON schema.table2 TO user_r;
```

таблицы создаю пользователем user_rw;

Comment: Так вы можете воспользоваться Spring Security для определенных комманд в контроллере. Или вы можете сделать свои аннотации привилегий и с помощью SpringAOP перехватывать вызовы и проверять есть ли пользователь в сессии и какой, и делать, как посчитаете нужным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете создать файл `import.sql` и положить его в root classpath'а, он исполнится всякий раз при создании схемы.

Comment: ну это запасной вариант

Comment: @Ohwgoodd, тогда не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите добиться

Comment: я хочу избавиться от sql скриптов, создание таблиц и индексов я делаю с помощью jpa, а вот права дать не могу

Comment: @Ohwgoodd, не припомню такой аннотации, можно конечно хранимую процедуру дёрнуть, но это видимо тоже не совсем то, что вам надо